# Java: Converting between bases with custom symbols

Tags: java, radix

I was wondering if you can create a custom base with your own symbols instead of the one Java applies to you with `Integer.parseInt` (`0-9` and `A-P`.)

I was thinking of something like this:

```
public class Base {
    private String symbols;
    public Base(String symbols) {
        this.symbols = symbols;
    }
    // for example: new Base("0123456789"); would represent base 10
    public static String convertBases(Base from, Base to, String toConvert) {
        // Takes toConvert which is encoded in base "from" and converts it to base "to"
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to implement this. Does anyone have the code for this?

Comment: So, after reading the question, the answer is, "Yes". Which leads to me believe the reason for the downvote is probably related to the fact that the question is overly broad in nature. *"Does such a class exist already?"* - Personally, I'm not aware of one, and this skirting "asking for offsite resources". To be honest, it's a little wishy washy. *"I believe this is a perfectly valid question"* - And welcome to the community - it doesn't always react in the way you might want

Comment: I down-voted because the method makes no sense. What do you expect the method to return? What does `Base.convertBases(new Base("01"), new Base("0123456789"))` do? I mean, it seems to want to convert base-2 to base-10, i.e. binary to decimal, but what *value* should it convert? What is expected return value for that call?

Comment: I might suggest making use `enum`s for a limited set of bases, which could then be used to provide a conversation point.  [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) might be an example

Comment: @MadProgrammer @Robby Cornelissen Sorry; what I meant to say was "Does anyone have the code for the class"? I updated it

@Andreas Sorry, didn't think of that. I updated the question and what I want it to do is to convert string `converted` (of base `from`) to the base `to`.

Comment: @D.B. That sample code will not allow you to do an alphabetic base-26 encoding

Comment: @D.B. That just converts it from base to base...I want it to be able to convert a base with custom symbols such as the alphabet.

Comment: It would take 5 minutes to implement a class like this for custom bases with custom digits. Why do you need someone else's code?

Comment: @Teddy Not homework...just curious. I need someone else's code because I don't know how to. If you could give me a basic outline on how to do it I could probably try to implement it

Comment: Ok.. I would have liked to see your not-working/trial code. I'll try to pitch in by posting a structure (class with method signatures).. :)

Comment: I downvoted because the question doesn't show evidence of prior effort. If you did try something, please [edit] to include it.

Comment: There you go.. my answer shows a general structure to implement custom bases. And @Andreas as provided the algorithm as well.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didnt reply, had to go. Will look over answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to first parse the input text in the `from` base, then format the value in the `to` base, exactly like you'd need to do if using standard base "alphabet".

```
public static String convertBases(int fromRadix, int toRadix, String text) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(text, fromRadix);
    return Integer.toString(value, toRadix);
}
```

So, first you implement `parse` and `toString`, then implementing `convertTo` is easy:

```
public class Base {
    private final String symbols;
    private final BigInteger radix;
    private final Map<Character, Integer> symbolIndex;
    public Base(String symbols) {
        if (symbols.length() <= 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide at least 2 symbols: length=" + symbols.length());
        this.symbols = symbols;
        this.radix = BigInteger.valueOf(symbols.length());
        this.symbolIndex = new HashMap<>(symbols.length() * 4 / 3 + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length(); i++) {
            Integer prevIndex = this.symbolIndex.putIfAbsent(symbols.charAt(i), i);
            if (prevIndex != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate symbol at index " + prevIndex +
                                                   " and " + i + ": " + symbols.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    public BigInteger parse(String text) {
        BigInteger value = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            Integer index = this.symbolIndex.get(text.charAt(i));
            if (index == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid number: " + text);
            value = value.multiply(this.radix).add(BigInteger.valueOf(index));
        }
        return value;
    }
    public String toString(BigInteger value) {
        if (value.signum() < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative value not allowed: " + value);
        if (value.signum() == 0)
            return this.symbols.substring(0, 1);
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (BigInteger v = value; v.signum() != 0; v = v.divide(this.radix))
            buf.append(this.symbols.charAt(v.mod(this.radix).intValue()));
        return buf.reverse().toString();
    }
    public String convertTo(Base newBase, String text) {
        return newBase.toString(parse(text));
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
Base base3 = new Base("012");
Base base6alpha = new Base("ABCDEF");
System.out.println(base3.convertTo(base6alpha, "0"));   // 0  -> A
System.out.println(base3.convertTo(base6alpha, "2"));   // 2  -> C
System.out.println(base3.convertTo(base6alpha, "10"));  // 3  -> D
System.out.println(base3.convertTo(base6alpha, "200")); // 18 -> DA
```

*Output*

```
A
C
D
DA
```

---

*Test 2*

```
Base obscure = new Base("^JsdloYF9%");
Base base64 = new Base("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/");
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("123456789012345678901234567890"); // Too large for int and long
String obscureValue = obscure.toString(value);
String base64Value = base64.toString(value);

System.out.println(obscureValue);
System.out.println(base64Value);
System.out.println(base64.convertTo(obscure, base64Value));
System.out.println(obscure.convertTo(base64, obscureValue));
```

*Output*

```
JsdloYF9%^JsdloYF9%^JsdloYF9%^
BjukP9sNz4O5OPwrS
JsdloYF9%^JsdloYF9%^JsdloYF9%^
BjukP9sNz4O5OPwrS
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a value type. It holds a string representation and a Base object. (i.e., it has a string representation and a something like a decoder). Why? because we don't want to pass around Strings which we need to look at and "guess" what base they are.

```
public class CustomNumber {
    private final String stringRepresentation;
    private final Base base;
    public CustomNumber(String stringRepresentation, Base base) {
        super();
        this.stringRepresentation = stringRepresentation;
        this.base = base;
    }


    public long decimalValue() {
        return base.toDecimal(stringRepresentation);
    }
    public CustomNumber toBase(Base newBase) {
        long decimalValue = this.decimalValue();
        String stringRep = newBase.fromDecimal(decimalValue);
        return new CustomNumber(stringRep, newBase);
    }
}
```

Then we need to define an interface which is broad enough to handle any regular or custom-symbol base. We will later build concrete implementations on top.

```
public interface Base {
        public long toDecimal(String stringRepresentation);
        public String fromDecimal(long decimalValue);
}
```

We are all set. Lets do an example implementation to support the standard decimal number format before going to custom string symbols:

```
public class StandardBaseLong implements Base{
    public long toDecimal(String stringRepresentation) {
        return Long.parseLong(stringRepresentation);
    }

    public String fromDecimal(long decimalValue) {
        return Long.toString(decimalValue);
    }
}
```

Now finally, coming to the custom string base:

```
public class CustomBase implements Base{
    private String digits;
    public CustomBase(String digits) {
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public long toDecimal(String stringRepresentation) {
        //Write logic to interpret that string as your base
        return 0L;
    }

    public String fromDecimal(long decimalValue) {
        //Write logic to generate string output in your base format
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you have a framework to work with various custom and standard bases.

Of course, there could be more customisations and improved features (more convenience constructors, hashCode and equals implementations and arithmetic). But, they are beyond the scope of this answer.